# JavaScript function to generate a numbered list within a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website, one of my TextAreas I want to have a number count each time a user goes to a new line, so each line has a number as if it was an ordered list. 
However I can't use the OL tag in html. I was looking for JS functions that could do this to a TextArea but so far nothing.

This seems pretty basic but I am struggling, any help is appreciated

Heres the textArea I want to have as a numbered list:

```html
<label class="label">Steps to Reproduce:<span class="required">*</span></label>
<textarea id="repro-steps-textarea"  required name="repro-steps" placeholder="1)...2)..." rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: The answer is "yes", but there are many different ways to accomplish this and, for that reason, your question is likely to be closed as "too broad". You should always post the code you are working with, and a **specific** question about that code, rather than generalized questions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Correct, so far I only have the HTML code and a few basic JS functions for the forms. I am unsure which code would help to better clear up my question. Any insight would be helpful

Comment: Again, always post the code that you are working with and ask a specific question.